# EventMachine only triggering keyboard handler's receive_line after an additional keypress

Tags: ruby, stdin, eventmachine

I've got a simple keyboard echo program here to test out EventMachine, as well as the equivalent code written without EM. It seems that EventMachine is only triggering the receive_line method after and additional keypress on Windows. Here is the eventmachine application:

```
class KeyboardHandler < EM::Connection
  include EM::Protocols::LineText2

  def post_init
    prompt
  end

  def prompt
    print "> "
  end

  def receive_line line
    line.chomp!
    case(line)
    when /^exit$/ then
      EM.stop
    else
      puts line
      prompt
    end
  end
end
EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.open_keyboard KeyboardHandler
}
```

Typing input then pressing enter will create a newline, but the typed line will not be echo'd back to the console until another keypress is made.
I created another snippet to test if it was a problem with the Windows console simply not flushing STDIN unitl another keypress, but this functions as one would expect, echoing back input after every return keypress:

```
while line = STDIN.readline
  puts "Typed #{line}"
end
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'd like EventMachine to trigger received_line after every return keypress immediately.